# How to implement a monitor in C++ using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, producer-consumer

I'm working on a [Producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) in C++ and what's the way to implement a monitor when using OpenMP?

I can't find anything like [conditional_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) in OpenMP and I can't implement waiting/notifying on certain conditions like in the wikipedia example.

Comment: Tell a bit more about how you want to do P-C problem in OpenMP, which to me doesn't fit P-C?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Is this a learning exercise to see if you can implement condition variables using only openMP constructs?  (That would be non-trivial.) Must you use an ancient system that lacks STL condition variables?  Had you never heard of STL? Type a little.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpenMP provides any means to use conditional variables, thus does not really fit your particular purpose.

OpenMP does not provide any constructs for conditional variables. Its purpose is more suited to multithreaded scientific applications, where you just partition the problem in small pieces and you don't think exactly about threads, since the synchronization is taken care by OpenMP's run-time library.

Some implementations use pthreads as a backend, so it might be possible to work around and use `pthread_cond` family functions. This however, is so prone to deadlocks (because you can't control how threads are created and joined) that is probably not going to be portable even with different versions of the same tools.

In your case, I would go straight with C++ standard thread library, which already includes all you need to implement your producer consumer queue. If you still want to stick to a parallel programming framework, give a look at Intel Thread Building Blocks, since it already implements such kind of [Concurrent Queues](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506081).

Comment: I agree completely, but "Don't do that"  is not an answer to the question. The question is rather too big to answer here.

Comment: I might not be clear enough, but my answer was more like: "You can't do it completely in OpenMP, and it is better to use other options". Thanks for the feedback though. I will update the answer to clarify that.

Comment: I think I could completely implement mutex and condition variables  in openMP, but I am not about to try it.

Comment: That is exactly my point. You need to implement it, is not something that is provided to you. OpenMP is not meant for users to do things on top of it. I've worked several years with OpenMP and similar shared memory programming models. It's not impossible, but it just does not worth even trying.